# Cannot compile solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, console-application

I have business layer in my solution. I added console project to the solution. Added necessary reference to console application. Created instances of classes in business layer. I'm using resharper so code looks correct.

when I try to build I get the error like

```
Error   127 The type or namespace name 'BusinessLayer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\ConsoleApplication\Program.cs    13  25
```

if I reference business layer from web project under the same solution it compiles, but with console it's not.

do you have any idea what can be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `using BusinessLayer;` in the top of your application, if you already did that, then try to clean and rebuild the solution.
Also make sure that both the library and the console application have the same .net framework version, for example both are 4.0 and not one of them 4.0 client profile...

Comment: I have the reference at the top of the page. I just cleaned and rebuild solution. Still have the same errors

Comment: Ok, does the library and the console application have the same .net framework version? for example both are 4.0 for example and not one of them 4.0 client profile...

Comment: you are right the problem was that console application had 4.0 client profile. Thank you  a lot for your help

Answer (score 1):

You seem to confuse a library (project) reference and a `using` statement judging by your comment:

> I have the reference at the top of the page.

You need both to add a reference (right-click your project's **References** folder in Solution Explorer > **Add Reference...**) *and* add a `using` directive at the top of the code file to import the required namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add a reference to that assembly from your console project.

You add references at the project level not the solution level, so the reference you added to your web application doesn't help your console app.

Comment: i said I added reference to console application(project) under the same solution

Answer (score 0):

Right click over your solution, configuration manager, you will see all projects, be sure that you have marked all necessary projects to build with right platform.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild the BusinessLayer class library and build your solution again.